# User's home directory gets owned by root during docker image build

Tags: docker

I'm trying to extend the `nodejs:latest` image by adding some additional packages and install the zsh shell with custom theme. I am unable to create any file in the `node` home directory `/home/node` as that will cause the entire home directory to be owned by root and I can't figure out what is causing that.

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN ls -al /home
RUN touch /home/node/test.txt
RUN ls -al /home
```

The first listing of the home directory shows that node owns its home directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jul 28 22:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug  7 22:18 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 node node 4096 Jul 28 22:03 node
```

The second listing of the home directory shows that root now owns the node directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jul 28 22:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug  7 22:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug  7 22:19 node
```

What is causing this directory to be owned by root? I have also used `USER node` before executing these commands but it has no effect. I have tried executing these commands as the node user but that also has the same outcome.

`Docker version 20.10.25, build 20.10.25-0ubuntu1~22.04.1`

Comment: Executing `RUN su - node -c "touch /home/node/test.txt && ls -al /home/node"` lists the node user still owning the home directory and the newly created file. Somewhere in between this step and the next one changes ownership to root. Can `Removing intermediate container` cause this?

Comment: `Removing intermediate container` is not the problem. I've used `--rm=false` and it still changes to root in between those steps.

Comment: Did you try it with [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/)?

Answer (score 0):

I thinkt it is a known bug that is fixed in `docker.io` version `20.10.25-0ubuntu1~20.04.2` / `20.10.25-0ubuntu1~22.04.2`. See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io-app/+bug/2029523/

Updates:

- Focal (20.04): [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io-app/20.10.25-0ubuntu1~20.04.2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io-app/20.10.25-0ubuntu1%7E20.04.2)
- Jammy (22.04): [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io-app/20.10.25-0ubuntu1~22.04.2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io-app/20.10.25-0ubuntu1%7E22.04.2)